# Can I get the Ubuntu dash in Xubuntu 13.04?

Tags: unity-dash, xubuntu

I'm using Xubuntu on an old computer and I wonder if it would be possible to have the Ubuntu 13.04 dash in it. I have tried using Ubuntu but it became too laggy. I basically just want it because it's much cooler than the default "finder".

Comment: What machine are you using?

Comment: Whichever machine OP is using, I very much doubt that the Unity Dash is available as a "plug-in" for Xubuntu.